# How to check tags uniqueness of tags using spatie/laravel-tags plugin

Tags: laravel-5, tags

Using [spatie/laravel-tags plugin](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-tags/v2/basic-usage/using-tags) in my Laravel 5.7 app.

I make editor of `tags`, so that admin would be able to add `tags` . However, I need to make validation on `tags` uniqueness.

Usual validation rules like

```
   'name' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        'max:255',
        Rule::unique(with(new Tag)->getTableName())->ignore($tag_id),
    ],
    'order_column'         => 'nullable|integer',
```

does not work here, as fields are in json format like:

```
{"en": "Drama"}
```

Could you, please, give a hint in which way this validation can be done?

MODIFIED BLOCK # 2
In my request `app/Http/Requests/TagRequest.php` I wrote validation rules:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Rules\TagUniqueness;


class TagRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        // $request= Request();

        return [
            'name' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'max:255',
                new TagUniqueness,
            ],
            'order_column'         => 'nullable|integer',
        ];

    }
}
```

and created rule `app/Rules/TagUniqueness.php` has:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class TagUniqueness implements Rule
{
    public function __construct()
    {
            $this->d( '<pre>TagUniqueness $_REQUEST::' . print_r( $_REQUEST, true ) );
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {

        $this->d( '<pre>passes  $attribute::' . print_r( $attribute, true ) );
        $this->d( '<pre>passes  $value::' . print_r( $value, true ) );
        return false;

    }

    ...
```

and I recieved this error:

```
 "message": "trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationRuleParser.php",
    "line": 217,
    "trace": [
        {
            "function": "handleError",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationRuleParser.php",
            "line": 217,
            "function": "trim"
        },
        {
            "file": "/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationRuleParser.php",
            "line": 199,
            "function": "parseArrayRule",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Validation\\ValidationRuleParser",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/src/Remote/Validator.php",
            "line": 161,
            "function": "parse",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Validation\\ValidationRuleParser",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/src/Remote/Validator.php",
            "line": 144,
            "function": "purgeNonRemoteRules",
            "class": "Proengsoft\\JsValidation\\Remote\\Validator",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/src/Remote/Validator.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "setRemoteValidation",
            "class": "Proengsoft\\JsValidation\\Remote\\Validator",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
```

as $this->d( my debugging method, I see output of TagUniqueness' s constructer, but passes method IS NOT CALLED and I can not define the reason of this error.

What is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible with the default Laravel validation rules, but you could create your own validation rules for this. [See here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: Remul, thank you for feeback.
Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK # 2